# ERROR: Input string was not in a correct format. Source: mscorlib

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Below datasource is showing following error when the selected index is changed. Datasource gets String as dropdownlist items. On changing the selected index 2nd time it gives this error.

> ERROR: Input string was not in a correct format. Source: mscorlib

HTML code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="menuService"
                  runat="server" 
                  onfocus="javascript:this.style.backgroundColor ='#FFFFEA';"
                  onChange="javascript:this.style.backgroundColor ='#FFFFEA';"
                  style="border: 1px solid dodgerblue; padding: 2px; z-index: 2; left: 10px; top: 185px; position: absolute; letter-spacing: 1px; cursor: pointer; visibility: visible; width: 168px; height: 24px; background-color: #FFFFEA; font-family: Tahoma, Arial; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt; line-height: normal;"
                  BackColor="#FFFFEA"
                  TabIndex="1"
                  AutoPostBack="True"
                  ForeColor="Navy"
                  Font-Bold="True"
                  DataSourceID="datasource_ServicesAndPhases"
                  DataTextField="ServiceAndPhase"
                  DataValueField="ServiceAndPhase">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Code-behind:

```
 Private Sub menuService_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles menuService.DataBound
 menuService.Items.Insert(0, " ")
  End Sub

  Private Sub menuService_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles menuService.SelectedIndexChanged

        menuService.Style("background-color") = "#FFFFEA"        

        menuService.Focus()

    End Sub
```

ERROR

```
Input string was not in a correct format.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +14777731
   System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +172
   System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider) +55
   System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, TypeCode typeCode, IFormatProvider provider) +404
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter.GetValue(Object value, String defaultValue, TypeCode type, Boolean convertEmptyStringToNull, Boolean ignoreNullableTypeChanges) +139
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter.GetValue(Object value, Boolean ignoreNullableTypeChanges) +89
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCollection.GetValues(HttpContext context, Control control) +287
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.InitializeParameters(DbCommand command, ParameterCollection parameters, IDictionary exclusionList) +301
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +704
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +26
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +138
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +45
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +162
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +256
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +256
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +6925
```

Comment: That is very definitely vb.net and not C#

Comment: after editing the html to make it more readable, it looks like it's malformed. The closing asp tag `/asp:DropDownList>` is missing the less than character, should be: `</asp:DropDownList>`

Comment: yes, thanks I changed it

Comment: Did that fix it, or was it just a side-effect of copying/pasting code?

Comment: no it was just a mistake in editing. I am not able to figure out the error as even the datatextfield and datavaluefield are correct as well as the datatype in sql.